# Accessing multiple child elements in a table xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I was trying to get this code

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent">
        <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="child"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

to display in a table each child element's value listed in a table. But as the person who could understand my English based explanation (Which I realise is considered bad form whereas I find word problems easier) I needed to do this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent">
        <xsl:for-each select="child">
        <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I didn't know about the way you could use "." to get each instance of the last part of the path.

Comment: This is very unclear.  Please [edit] your post and include both input and desired output XML/HTML. Also explain why you think you can _"only get data from one child three times"_

Comment: Can you please edit your question again to show the input actually containing "Robert", "Tim" and "John", as well as your expected output? Thank you!

Comment: The main reason I refrained from using my actual code was because it showed too many other things that were identifying and nothing to do with Robert, Tim or John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *I have multiple child elements and I want them to display in the same row of a table, but I can only get data from one child*
You need to change your for `for-each` to iterate over children.
Try something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent/child">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Yes I didn't know about "." and I needed an extra for-each loop to what I was using.